# pyspark sql jdbc error - Incorrect syntax near the keyword &apos;SET&apos;

Tags: sql, sql-server, jdbc, pyspark, connection

Following is the SQL Sample which Im trying to run, but its is giving me error - ***.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'

```
tp_temp = """
SET NOCOUNT ON
declare @lp_dt dt = (select max(pt_dt) from [DB_TABLE].[db].[DATA] where p_type='WSD')
declare @L_dte tb (pt, pt_type char(1))

insert into @L_dte  SELECT pt_dt, pt_type
  FROM from [DB_TABLE].[db].[DATA]
  where (PT_Type = 'Z' and Month(pt_dt) in (1,4,7,10) and pt_dt > '2017 Sep 1') or (PT_Type = 'K' and pt_dt = @lp_dt )
group by pt_dt, PT_Type
order by pt_dt

SELECT z_id_alt, z_id, z_Status_Alt, c_Gp_CCD, Gender, Age, ctk as CTK_Red, CAT_Title, temp_Group, Comp_price, terminator_action_alt AS Terminator_Action, v_pt.PT_Dt,CASE 
    WHEN COALESCE([Acb_Indicator], '') = ''
        THEN ('No')
    ELSE ('Yes')
    END AS  [Is Acb],
                     COALESCE(nullif([Region_Desc_NEWCO_Original], ''), Region_Desc_NEWCO) AS Region_Desc_NEWCO,
                     COALESCE(nullif([POG3_Desc_Original], ''), POG3_Desc) AS  POG3_Desc,
                      COALESCE(nullif([POG9_Desc_Original], ''), POG9_Desc) AS POG9_Desc, COALESCE(nullif(BSD_Function, ''), OrgUnit_Function_L2_NEWCO) as OrgUnit_Function_L2_NEWCO, CASE 
    WHEN COALESCE(nullif([POG3_Desc_Original], ''), POG3_Desc) IN (
            SELECT [POG_Desc]
            FROM [DB_FREE].[dbz].[Free_dom]
            WHERE POG_Type = 'POG3'
            )
        OR COALESCE(nullif([POG9_Desc_Original], ''), POG9_Desc) IN (
            SELECT [POG_Desc]
            FROM [DB_FREE].[dbz].[Free_dom]
            WHERE POG_Type = 'POG9'
            )
        THEN 'Yes'
    ELSE 'No'
    END AS [Restricted_Home], Zero) AS Booring
    FROM   (SELECT * FROM [DB_FREE].[dbz].[Free_dom] WHERE noshow = 'N' AND E_Type <> 'SubConsole') as v_pt
    INNER JOIN @l_pt_dt as pt_dt on v_pt.pt_dt = pt_dt.pt_dt and v_pt.pt_type = pt_dt.pt_type
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [DB_TABLE].[db].[DATA] AS o_p ON o_p.[u_number] = v_pt.ete_idg """

df_temp= spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=tp_temp, properties=connectionProperties)
```

For simple SQL starting with Select command it works but for code starting with SET or WITH it throws errors, please let me know how I can create a table from this SQL code in pyspark dataframe

Comment: Remove the first parenthesis and the closing one corresponding to it. Why did you attempt to enclose the entire batch in them?

Comment: And attempting to order your rows in the table variable is pointless. Your final query has no order by clause so the rows in your final resultset have no guaranteed order. If that is important, you must include an order by clause in that final statement. Lastly, develop good tsql habits. Start terminating all statements - eventually it will be required.

Comment: And lastly - after carefully reading the query, it seems you don't use your table variable at all. So why - just WHY?

Comment: Even after removing the parenthesis the error persists, plz ignore the authenticity of the SQL code - I had to delete some of it for security purposes.